# How should I be building a ranged Vanquisher?

Tags: torchlight

I've been playing a Vanquisher for some time, using mostly dual-pistols and ranged attacks. I've been upgrading my Dexterity and picking up skills like Exploding shot and other things that seem like they'd increase my damage, but I've largely just been "winging it": picking things that sound cool or upgrading to items with more lines of attributes on them.

It's worked okay so far, but I'd like to *aim* for something in the rest of my play-through. I think I'm comfortable with my skill selections (Exploding shot and Ricochet, and spending almost all the rest in passives), but what *should* I be looking for—with respect to attributes—when trying to build a ranged vanquisher?

Should I be dumping all my attribute points into Dexterity, or is there a more balanced allocation?

Assuming I'm not trying to create a novelty build (like maxing out one stat—say, crit chance—at the sake of ignoring everything else that might be needed to get through the game without grinding my teeth—like say, survivability), what item attributes and runes should I be looking at?

Are there must-have attributes for Vanquishers, regardless of playstyle? Are there attributes that look good on paper, but don't really work as advertised?

Comment: Str is useful for wearing armor. Unfortunately, it's not obvious how much STR you will need for that *epic drop of awesome* until its too late. Other gear requries DEF or Magic. I usually build straight 3Dex / 2Def, getting STR or MAG as needed for gear.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for sure what is the 'best' build, but one thing I've found that made the game much easier when I played it is having a very high chance to reflect projectiles.  I built my vanquisher mostly like you, focusing a lot on ricochet and exploding shot, ranged damage, and critical hit and putting most points into dex, with some into other stats as needed for better gear.  Basically I was a glass cannon, the only problem I had was survivability from ranged and magic attacks.

One thing that made my game exceedingly easy was to find a pretty low leveled shield with +20% or higher chance to reflect projectiles, and then enchanting it a few times.  You need to get very lucky (and let the enchanting succeed 8-10 times without wiping the item).  On top of that, what you want is to have the item to go over 100% chance to reflect ranged attacks.  This, in effect, made you immune to all ranged attacks as well as magic (I'm not sure if this is currently still the case as I haven't played the game for a year).  This made the Dark Zealots (and their insane damage magic attack) much easier to handle.  All I had to do after getting that shield was to maintain my distance and kill everything with exploding shot.